# Cannot save data in the joint table in many to many relationship using codefirst

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, ef-code-first

I'm new to EntityFramework's code first. So I'm running some simple tests to learn. I created two classes: Team and Player that hypothetically have a many to many relationship. I also enabled-migration and added some seed data. When I run update-database, I see that the seed data populate the Teams and Players tables but the TeamPlayers table is empty. Any clues as what is wrong in the code? (I have removed the package inclusions here for simplicity of presentation)

```
namespace CodeFirst_onetomany.Models
{
    public class Team
    {
        public Team()
        {
            this.Players = new HashSet<Player>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string TeamName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace CodeFirst_onetomany.Models
{
    public class Player
    {
        public Player()
        {
            this.Teams = new HashSet<Team>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace CodeFirst_onetomany.Models
{
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyContext() : base("MyDbOneToMany")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace CodeFirst_onetomany.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<CodeFirst_onetomany.Models.MyContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(CodeFirst_onetomany.Models.MyContext context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
            //
            //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
            //      p => p.FullName,
            //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
            //    );
            //

            context.Teams.AddOrUpdate(t => t.TeamName, new Team() { TeamName = "AC Milan" });
            context.Teams.AddOrUpdate(t => t.TeamName, new Team() { TeamName = "Barcelona" });

            context.SaveChanges();

            context.Players.AddOrUpdate(p => new { p.FirstName, p.LastName },
                new Player()
                {
                    FirstName = "Paolo",
                    LastName = "Maldini",
                    Teams = new List<Team>() { context.Teams.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TeamName == "AC Milan") }
                });

            context.Players.AddOrUpdate(p => new { p.FirstName, p.LastName },
                new Player()
                {
                    FirstName = "Leo",
                    LastName = "Messi",
                    Teams = context.Teams.ToList()
                });

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: So I removed the HashSets (thanks for the info on that @Harald Coppoolse) and started storing info in variables so I could debug it... I also added two additional lines adding teams to players at the end. So I partially have:

```
context.Players.AddOrUpdate(p => new { p.FirstName, p.LastName }, maldini);
context.Players.AddOrUpdate(p => new { p.FirstName, p.LastName }, messi);
context.Players.FirstOrDefault(p => p.FirstName == "Paolo").Teams = shouldBeMilan;
context.Players.FirstOrDefault(p => p.FirstName == "Leo").Teams = shouldBeBarcaMilan;

context.SaveChanges();
```

and it now works. So I guess one would have to manually add the relationship between players and teams in EF and we cant rely on the object creation (i.e. using new). I have no idea why though!

Comment: I think you have to add to the mapping table manually, as you have done for Team and Player class.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a Team with some Players without using migrations?

By the way: try this without creatin a HashSet in the constructor. It is a waste of processing power, since it will be replaced by entity framework immediately by its own ICollection.

The following worked for me in a normal Program.Main() without hashset:

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext(...)
{
     var team1 = dbContext.Teams.Add(new Team() {TeamName = "Team 1"});

     var team2 = dbContext.Teams.Add(new Team()
     {
          TeamName = "My Super Team",
          Players =  new List<Player>()
          {
               new Player() {FirstName = "Christopholo", LastName = "Columbo"},
               new Player() {FirstName = "Marco", LastName = "Polo"},
          },
     });

     var player1 = dbContext.Players.Add(new Player()
     {
          FirstName = "X1",
          LastName = "Y1",
     });

     var player2 = dbContext.Players.Add(new Player()
     {
          FirstName = "X2",
          LastName = "Y2",
          Teams = new List<Team>() {team1, team2, new Team() {TeamName = "Team3"});
     });

     dbContext.SaveChanges();

     var teams = dbContext.Teams.Select(team => new
         {
             Id = team.Id,
             Name = team.Name,
             Players = team.Players.Select(player => new
             {
                 Id = player.Id,
                 LastName = player.LastName,
             })
             .ToList(),
         })
         .ToList();

     var players = dbContext.Players.Select(player => new
         {
              Id = player.Id,
              LastName = player.LastName,
              Teams = player.Teams.Select(team => new
              {
                  Id = team.Id,
                  Name = team.TeamName,
              })
              .ToList(),
         })
         .ToList();
         .ToList();
}
```

Does this work? And what if you add a player to this Team?

```
// add a Player using the Team's collection:
var teamToUpdate = dbContext.Teams.Where(team => team.Id ==team1.Id;
teamToUpdate.Players.Add(new Player() {FirstName = "...", LastName = "..."});

// add a Player and give him a Team:
var addedPlayer = dbContext.Player(new Player()
{
     FirstName = ...,
     LastName = ...,
     Teams = new List<Team>() {teamToUpdate},
})
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

And what happens if you do this while using `AddOrUpdate`?

I've tried this (all without HashSet) and it works.

Advise: First get it working without the migration, then try to do it in your migration. Debug it with breakpoints, are you really migrating?